# DEAP: create individual with certain values

Tags: python, deap

I have a DEAP toolbox setup

```
import random
from deap import base, tools, creator, algorithms

toolbox = base.Toolbox()

creator.create("FitnessMax", base.Fitness, weights=(1.0,))
creator.create("Individual", list, fitness=creator.FitnessMax)
toolbox.register("individual", tools.initRepeat, creator.Individual, random.random, n=2)

toolbox.register("population", tools.initRepeat, list, toolbox.individual)
```

I want to force the value of certain individuals in the population. For this, I would like to create individuals that have a given genome and add them to the population

```
pop = toolbox.population(n=10)
new_individual = ?
pop.append(new_individual)
```

How do I define the new individual? Doing `new_individual = toolbox.individual([.1, .2])` doesn't work. Nor does `new_individual = toolbox.individual(); new_individual.values = [.1, .2]`. If I do `new_individual = [.1, .2]`, then it no longer has the right type (`list` rather than `deap.creator.Individual`.

Answer (score 0):

One way is the following: new_individual = creator.Individual(individual_values)

### Boilerplate example (for context):

```
from deap import base, creator, tools
import numpy as np


creator.create("FitnessMax", base.Fitness, weights=(1.0,))

creator.create("Individual", list, fitness=creator.FitnessMax)

toolbox = base.Toolbox()

toolbox.register('evaluate', lambda x: fitness_fn(x, **fitness_fn_kwargs))

toolbox.register("attr_int", np.random.randint, low = 0, high = nvals)

toolbox.register("individual", tools.initRepeat, creator.Individual, toolbox.attr_int, n = npars)

toolbox.register("population", tools.initRepeat, list, toolbox.individual)

pop = toolbox.population(n=pop_size)
```

### replace the values of one individual:

```
pop[0] = creator.Individual(10 * [0])
```